# AVPlayer resume capability

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer in a table view.I want to start video playing where I stop video playing when scroll table view.Tell me what are the possible ways to do it?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"tableIdentifier";
CustomTableCell *cell = [self.videoTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"VideoCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
}
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    AVAsset *avAssert = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"]];
    cell.playerItem =[[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:avAssert];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (!cell.avPlayer) {
            cell.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:cell.playerItem];
        }else{
            [cell.avPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:cell.playerItem];
        }
        if (!cell.avPlayerLayer) {
            cell.avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:cell.avPlayer];
            cell.avPlayerLayer.frame = cell.videoPlayerView.layer.bounds;
            cell.avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize;
            [cell.videoPlayerView.layer addSublayer: cell.avPlayerLayer];
            if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                cell.avPlayer.muted = NO;
                [cell.avPlayer play];
            }
        }
    });
});
return cell;
```

}

Comment: you have to maintain a array of duration of videos at which you pause video and when again you scroll to same video, first check start playing video from duration in array

Comment: Currently I'm doing what you said.problem is i'm reusing the cell. somtimes it does not take correct AVPlayerItem current time.i'll try and let you know.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how Apple did something like this in a sample app (I do it differently):

```
/* When the app goes to the background, save the media url and time values
 to the application preferences. */
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application
{
    if (self.playbackViewController)
    {
        NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSURL* URL = [self.playbackViewController URL];

        if (URL)
        {
            NSTimeInterval time = CMTimeGetSeconds([[self.playbackViewController player] currentTime]);

            [defaults setURL:URL forKey:AVPlayerDemoContentURLUserDefaultsKey];
            [defaults setDouble:time forKey:AVPlayerDemoContentTimeUserDefaultsKey];
        }
        else
        {
            [defaults removeObjectForKey:AVPlayerDemoContentURLUserDefaultsKey];
            [defaults removeObjectForKey:AVPlayerDemoContentTimeUserDefaultsKey];
        }

        [defaults synchronize];
    }
}
```

In either (or both) the appDidFinishLaunching or appDidEnterForeground methods:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    /* Restore saved media time value from defaults system. */
    [[self.playbackViewController player] seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds([defaults doubleForKey:AVPlayerDemoContentTimeUserDefaultsKey], NSEC_PER_SEC)]; 
}

return YES;
}
```